# Spring data кидвет java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Здраствуйте, мучююсь с ошибкой уже дней 5.При запросе к UserRepository кидaет ошибку java.lang.NullPointerException.

aplication.properties

```
server.port=4001

# ---- Postgres ----
spring.datasource.driverClassName =org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/BodaDB

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=jpa

spring.datasource.username=Boda
spring.datasource.password=Boda1006

#JPA logging
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
# create
# none
# update
# create-drop

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Мой Entity

package com.example.demo.Models;

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Table(name = "users")
@Entity
public class Users {
    @Column(name="email")
    String email;
    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    public Users() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Users(String email, String login, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Мой Repository

```
package com.example.demo.Repositories;

import com.example.demo.Models.Users;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users,Long> {
}
```

Мой Класс с использованием spring data

package com.example.demo.Configures;

```
import com.example.demo.Repositories.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example.demo")
public class DemoApplication {
    @Autowired
    private static UserRepository userRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    userRepository.findAll();

    }


}
```

Comment: main должен запускать спринг бут приложение, а магия должна происходить в сервисах и контроллерах. А вы намешали всё в одну кучу

Answer (score 0):

Не работает, так как static несовместим c @Autowired + нет main метода (SpringApplication.run).

Попробуй

```
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example.demo")
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private  UserRepository userRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Почитать об  @Autowired:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation

Comment: Да спасибо ошибка была в этом.